# PL/SQL Function not returning correct value

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following function which is meant to return the number of rows that match the parameters:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION FIUCIRCUITO(circuito IN EVENTOS.CIRCUITO%TYPE, anio IN EVENTOS.AÑO%TYPE, mes IN EVENTOS.MES%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER IS fiu NUMBER(8,2);
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO fiu FROM EVENTOS WHERE MES = mes AND AÑO = anio AND CIRCUITO = circuito;
  RETURN fiu;
END FIUCIRCUITO;
```

but when I call it with `select FIUCIRCUITO('AEREOPUERTO 1', 2019, 05) from dual;` it returns a strange number: 1546. When I do the the Select statement on its own `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EVENTOS WHERE MES = 05 AND AÑO = 2019 AND CIRCUITO = 'AEROPUERTO 1';` it returns the correct result which is 8.
What could be my error?

Comment: `WHERE MES = mes and CIRCUITO = circuito` works like `1=1`. Change parameter names, they are now same as column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to start parameters with a prefix, usually p_, or something including the datatype too; pn_ for numbers, pv_ for VARCHAR2.
Your function will look like this:

```
    create or replace FUNCTION FIUCIRCUITO(p_circuito IN EVENTOS.CIRCUITO%TYPE, p_anio IN EVENTOS.AÑO%TYPE, p_mes IN EVENTOS.MES%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER IS fiu NUMBER(8,2);
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO fiu FROM EVENTOS WHERE MES = p_mes AND AÑO = p_anio AND CIRCUITO = p_circuito;
  RETURN fiu;
END FIUCIRCUITO;
```

Now, the parser does not confuse the parameter for the name of the column, which is the same (MES =mes is parsed as  the column name twice).